# Is it possible to override locale of one specific intl.formatMessage?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I use `react-intl` with `en` and `fr`, and my React app is wrapped in

```
<IntlProvider locale={lang}>
```

so that e.g. when `lang` is `en`, all `intl.formatMessage` calls result in English texts.

What I want to achieve is that I want `<IntlProvider locale="en">`, but inside the app, I need one specific `intl.formatMessage` to be translated into `fr`.

Comment: if you have JSON files for translations of both languages, can you maybe put the `fr` one inside the corresponding `en` translation?

Comment: thank you for a hint tanmay, but I need to access both `en` and `fr` version of the same text at the same time on one page, e.g. like to print "Good day" and "Bon Jour" together ( both defined e.g. as `messages.hello`).

Comment: went through their docs/issues, found nothing significant. Maybe you could go ahead and create an issue for this question.. they might have a workaround..

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add several `IntlProvider` in the same container. You must define for each the locale and the messages.
Here a sample just with a FormattedMessage, but it can be bigger element:

```
<div>
  <IntlProvider locale='en' messages={messagesEn} >
    <FormattedMessage value={message.hello} />
  </IntlProvider>

  <IntlProvider locale='fr' messages={messagesFr} >
    <FormattedMessage value={message.hello} />
  </IntlProvider>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, what I actually need is to embed one IntlProvider into another, like this: https://gist.github.com/petervojtek/c79bb05643f33dc0e44d1b993569f1d9
but that doesnt seem to be working and the inner translation is also in english and warning in console says "[React Intl] Error formatting message: "app.hello" for locale: "fr", using default message as fallback.
TypeError: A message must be provided as a String or AST."

Comment: the messages are specified this way: https://gist.github.com/petervojtek/c30fe6553bb6c1a6d520e326c9537f38

Answer (score 0):

You can use `separate intl object` using: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api#createintl

Then use it e.g.:

```
const frIntlCache = createIntlCache()

const frIntl = createIntl({
  locale: 'fr-FR',
  messages: {messagesEn}
}, frIntlCache)

<IntlProvider locale='en' messages={messagesEn} >
  <FormattedMessage id='message.hello' />         // Hello
  {frIntl.formatMessage({id: 'message.hello'})}   // Bonjour
</IntlProvider>
```